# Why would an Android emulator be listed as 'host' in adb devices?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Recently I stumbled across a log on a server which runs emulators for our CI testing, where one emulator of several was persistently listed as 'host' instead of the usual 'device' or occasional 'offline' in the output of adb devices. (Until its watchdog got bored and killed it.)

```
[18:49:37]   168    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14040 Sep 20 19:35 /tmp/watchlog
[18:49:37]   169         1  List of devices attached
[18:49:37]   170         2  emulator-5570   device
[18:49:37]   171         3  emulator-5568   device
[18:49:37]   172         4  emulator-5566   device
[18:49:37]   173         5  emulator-5564   device
[18:49:37]   174         6  emulator-5562   device
[18:49:37]   175         7  emulator-5560   device
[18:49:37]   176         8  emulator-5558   device
[18:49:37]   177         9  emulator-5556   device
[18:49:37]   178        10  emulator-5554   device
[18:49:37]   179        11  emulator-5572   host
```

They're each in their own docker container, started from the same image, connecting to an ADB server on the default port 5037 in the controller container, and they're running --net=host.

Host looks like what I'd expect to see if I ran adb devices inside an emulator, so I'm guessing some sort of port number clash due to remapping, but adb isn't running on any 55xx port. Or maybe adb instances cook up some random id and this just happened to match the daemon's? (Do I win a prize?)

I don't know how frequent this is - I've never thought to monitor for weird statuses.

---

Update: I looked more closely at the container output, and there's a connection refused for 5573. If I start an emulator up with its adb port already in use (by nc -lk), it simply never shows up in adb - it doesn't list as host.

```
[18:49:37]    35    == STATUS: 2019-09-20.19:32:03 emulator-starting-5572
[18:49:37]    36    + emulator -no-window -no-boot-anim -no-audio -gpu swiftshader_indirect -avd avdmanager-creation -port 5572 -no-snapshot-save
[18:49:37]    37    localhost [127.0.0.1] 5573 (?) : Connection refused
[18:49:37]    38    /local/emulauncher.sh: line 213:    77 Done                    echo ping
[18:49:37]    39            78 Killed                  | timeout -s9 3 nc localhost $[ ${EMULATOR_PORT} + 1 ]
[18:49:37]    40    qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TSC frequency mismatch between VM (1999997 kHz) and host (3399999 kHz), and TSC scaling unavailable
[18:49:37]    41    qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TSC frequency mismatch between VM (1999997 kHz) and host (3399999 kHz), and TSC scaling unavailable
[18:49:37]    42    60...emulator: Requested console port 5572: Inferring adb port 5573.
[18:49:37]    43    Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
[18:49:37]    44     - Start Android Studio
[18:49:37]    45     - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
[18:49:37]    46     - Click "SDK Tools" tab
[18:49:37]    47     - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
[18:49:37]    48     - Click "OK"
```

The killed/ping/timeout-nc stuff the watchdog doing something that seemed to wake up the emulator when it occasionally remained offline, although the use of 'ping' makes me wonder whether I had intended to send that to qemu rather than the adb port. 60... comes from the watchdog countdown.

Answer (score 2):

For all you know it's just some random process listening at the port number in the range that `adb` considers belonging to emulators. `adb` sends a command to the port and then parses the reply when trying to figure out the connection status.

And the "host" status is just the [default option](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android10-release/adb/adb.cpp#270):

```
const std::string& type = pieces[0];
if (type == "bootloader") {
    D("setting connection_state to kCsBootloader");
    t->SetConnectionState(kCsBootloader);
} else if (type == "device") {
    D("setting connection_state to kCsDevice");
    t->SetConnectionState(kCsDevice);
} else if (type == "recovery") {
    D("setting connection_state to kCsRecovery");
    t->SetConnectionState(kCsRecovery);
} else if (type == "sideload") {
    D("setting connection_state to kCsSideload");
    t->SetConnectionState(kCsSideload);
} else if (type == "rescue") {
    D("setting connection_state to kCsRescue");
    t->SetConnectionState(kCsRescue);
} else {
    D("setting connection_state to kCsHost");
    t->SetConnectionState(kCsHost);
}
```

Comment: Nice hypothesis! I'll look at the logs and run some tests once I'm at work, though I would have expected the emulator to quit claiming the port was in use, thereby killing the emulator's container since the emulator is the last thing in the entry point shell script.

Comment: I can't get 'host' showing up, even if I 'nc' the port busy or try 'adb -P 5555' before running the emulator. I've added some netstat logging in the watchdog loop to try to get more info, in case I spot it again.